# what is written in the end of (manuscript) fugue of BWV 998?

Tags: notation, sheet-music

By the end of fugue of BWV 998 (manuscript), we have this:

[image: last measure of fugue]

Which should connect with the 4th measure:

[image: first measures of fugue]

But I have no idea of what it says in the last measure... nor do I see anything on the 4th measure that makes me think that it is coming back to this spot.

What is written in the end of fugue then?

Here's the last system of fugue (where the last measure can be seen) and the first of the allegro:

[image: last system of fugue and first of allegro]

Comment: I'm a bit too tired to grasp the whole structure and analyze the complete piece, but, *anyway* it would really help if you'd explicitly clarify *why* that final bar should "connect" with the 4th measure: not everybody is that familiar/accustomed to the "art of fugue". Also, you say that the first image is is "by the end". Which bar? I can only find a similar excerpt 27 bars before the end (which is not really "by the end"). Is there a public reference we can see for that? It seems IMLSP only provides the manuscript for the Prelude, and any other version doesn't have any of that near the end.

Comment: Here's the link to the full manuscript on imslp: https://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ImagefromIndex/112000/pefw

Comment: Then.... what makes me think that it is going back to measure 4 is that the last 3 beats of the last measure match the last 3 beats of the 3rd measure.... also, that is how people play it (at least the versions I have seen/heard.... not to say that the momentum begs to not stop there, it is yelling to go back somewhere). Maybe there is a rule that _has_ to be followed when playing fugues? I left the conservatory before I hit the classes about counterpoint and fugue so if what I am missing is a piece of information in that direction (a rule, perhaps?), please, feel free to share it.

Comment: And just so that my motive to ask is clear: I am working on putting up the manuscript translated to lilypond as part of https://github.com/eantoranz/bwv (and I love the whole piece) so if there's something that has to be written on the last measure (and there appears to be some text or signs written there.... I just don't know what they are), then I would like for it to end up in my translation.

Comment: I've been listening to 2 versions ([this](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=HT7yP191zZA) and [this](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6NaUsWK0es)) while following your manuscript, and it seems that it is missing *a lot* of lines. This can also be confirmed by the fact that the link you gave us shows a ***very*** different alignment between the last lines of the fugue and the first of the allegro (which is completely inconsistent with the following systems) and the form is absolutely harmonically incomplete. Have you tried to properly and carefully listen to performances while following that score?

Comment: Now that you bring it up, no. Was going from memory (while listening to the produced midi from my translation).... but might be the case. Interesting. Will go through it tomorrow morning.

Comment: Ok.... I was curious enough to get out of bed. So.... Just checked (not that I was able to listen in my head to the notes as I read them from my translation of the manuscript... just following structure and movements) and it matched both versions (oh, Anna! Gotta love her). When you say that it is misaligned/incomplete, you mean like there's stuff missing from the fugue after the last measure **in the manuscript**? Ah, sure... what is missing is what is written from measures 4 up to the fermata on measure 29. Maybe I am misunderstanding your question/comment now.

Comment: So, **somehow** it is saying right there something like **go to measure 4.... up to the fermata** (I don't see a **fine** in the manuscript on measure 29, by the way... but I might be easily mistaken).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word at the end of the fugue is "capo", meaning "head" or "back to the beginning". However, it's clear from context — that being that the final measure matches measure 3 — that Bach intended a return to measure 4.

Looking back an additional couple of measures from the end, we can see that the Eb-D-Eb from the opening bar appears on beats 2, 3, and 4 of the middle voice three measures from the end. And in the second measure from the end, the downbeats match the second measure of the piece, excluding the Bb on beat 2, which is on the second sixteenth note.

The fermata at measure 29 is, by convention, understood as the *fine*. It's the only clear cadence in Eb.